# Magento2 - update to custom status after shipment creation

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin

I created an Observer that makes some execution based on the company needs using event `sales_order_shipment_save_after`. It does everything I need except changing the order status to a specific.

I both using Magento `setState/setStatus` and running an SQL update script directly, but none won´t make the change.

I looked for running a **plugin** instead of the **observer** but I could not find where should the plugin fit.

It´s important to let you know that the state is the same as the one set by shipment - complete. Only the status needs to be updated.

```
$orderState = Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
    $order2 = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_id);
    $order2->setState($orderState)->setStatus("entregue_transportadora");

    $order2->save();
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Share your code that you have used to update satatus

Comment: @ShoaibMunir I added the part of the code by the end of the observer that should make the status update but did not work. Thanks !

Comment: Make sure `entregue_transportadora` status is set to `complete` state. Verify from **Stores -> Settings -> Order Status**

Comment: @ShoaibMunir yep it is set to complete state, but it is not default status. The default status for complete is another. When I add the shipment the status is set to the default complete status and won´t change to this one.